# Align HTC Vive Coordinate with OptiTrack System in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, coordinate-systems, htc-vive

I am working on aligning HTC Vive Controller (for example, right controller) with a rigid body marker which is tracked by Optitrack. Since the coordinate system of both systems are different how can I align these two systems? I am trying to move the rigid body marker similar to the right-hand controller of the htc vive.

Scenario:

I have a unity environment which is viewed using HTC Vive and now I want to have a rigid body marker which is tracked by Optitrack and have to align properly while I move the marker in the environment.

Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently facing the same problem and have no solution yet, but some ideas:

**1st idea match the centers**

When you calibrate OptiTrack you set the center of your OptiTrack Space.
Maybe you can track the OptiTrack center point with the vive controller and then shift the vive's coordinate space appropriately.

I don't have an idea how to solve the rotation missmatch, maybe you have one?

**2nd idea track some reference points with both systems**

If you have the possibility to track 4 reference points in both systems, you should be able to define a transformation matrix from one vector space to the other.

For now, i have not tried the ideas, but i will soon.
Have you found a solution yet?